# Cocos2d HTML5 turn off anti aliasing

Tags: html, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Does anyone know, how to turn off antialiasing in Cocos2d HTML5? I know it is possible in cocos2d, but i can't seem to find it in the HTML5 version.
I'm trying to down and upscale a Sprite (0.5x and 2x), but it gets blurry no matter what i do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If anyone else is wondering, it is not possible yet. Don't waste your time for searching an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebGL mode, please modify the 'antialias' to true in cocos2d/core/platform/CCApplication.js, like this:

```
    cc.renderContext = cc.webglContext = cc.create3DContext(localCanvas,{
        'stencil': true,
        'preserveDrawingBuffer': true,
        'antialias': !cc.Browser.isMobile,
        'alpha': false});
```

Hopes to help.

Comment: Which version of Cocos2d HTML5 are you using?
On the other hand, i want to turn OFF AA, not on. How would it help me setting it to 'true'?